# Laravel Resource Collection: "Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::$map"

Tags: laravel

I am currently trying out Laravel Resource. Single resource works fine. But Resource Collection throws me the following error:

> "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$map"

**UserController.php**

```php
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
    {
        return [
            'success' => true, 
            'data' => new UserCollection(User::all())
        ];        
    }

     public function show(User $user)
     {
        return [
            'success' => true, 
            'data' => new UserResource($user)
        ];
    }
}
```

**UserCollection.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $count = $this->collection->count();
        
        return [
            'count' => $count,
            'data' => $this->collection
        ];
    }
}
```

The error clearly comes from this line: `'data' => $this->collection`. I suspect $this->collection iterates over the user collection. If I dd($this->collection) I correctly get all 51 items from the database. from the database:

**output dd($this->collection) inside resource collection)**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1380 ▼ //
app/Http/Resources/UserCollection.php:18
  #items: array:51 [▶]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

**What do I have to change to make it work?** Thanks in advance, Mike!

Comment: Just doublechecking, in the docs they say they use it like so: UserCollection::collection(User::all()) https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections have you tried this too?

Comment: new UserCollection is normally used for one User Model, the static UserCollection::collection(User::all()) method would be used for Collections...

Comment: @Techno I try it and i got this error: `Call to undefined method App\Models\User`. BadMethodCallException.

Comment: Thanks, but `Call to undefined method App\Models\User` seems incomplete. Is it complaining that the function `all()` is not defined? If so, can you verify that `User` class extends Model(directly or indirectly)?

Comment: @Aless55 I want customize my response. That the reason why i create explicit the UserCollection Resource. The way what you offer is correct if i want only the data collection. `Note that this does not allow any addition of custom meta data that may need to be returned with your collection. If you would like to customize the resource collection response, you may create a dedicated resource to represent the collection:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this?

```
return [
    'count' => $count,
    'data' => UserResource::collection($this->collection)
];
```

Comment: In principle, yes. I followed this tutorial and there it is done on the way up.
https://blog.shahednasser.com/beginners-guide-to-laravel-resources/

Comment: I think the code should work as I wrote it, I have something similar in my projects.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I will got this error: `"message": "Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::$id",
 "exception": "ErrorException",
 "file":
 "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/DelegatesToResource.php",
 "line": 139,`

Comment: My UserResource toArray() methods looks like:  `public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->resource->id,
            'name' => $this->resource->firstname,
            'email' => $this->resource->email
        ];
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }`

Comment: What is `$this->resource`, shouldn't that be only `$this->id`?

Comment: That article you shared seems badly written, I'd stick to the official documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: I also have the feeling that the tutorial is bad. I just made the adjustment `$this->id` instead of `$this->resource->id`. However, the error remains the same. Then I restored the default in my USerCollection toArray function. So `return parent::toArray($request)`.  Now I have a new error message: `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Resources\User::toArray(), 0 passed in /var/.../JsonResource.php on line 121 and exactly 1 exprected`.  I will apparently write again according to the official Laravel documentation.

Comment: And now it works. The Tutorial is indeed not so good. Thank you for this useful advice. That answers my question. Merci for your time and have a nice day!